# Circle CI how to store secure data

Tags: continuous-integration, continuous-deployment, circleci

I read about this post 
https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/env-vars/

and I need to store password in secure way, I put it in env and it's working but If Im doing something like in the  `.circleci/config.yml`

```
run: echo $mypass
```

I now that in other tools when you want to echo field as password
you will **get asterisks** , is there a way to do it in circleCi ? 
I need a way to store user and password in secure way

is there any reserved words for secure fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variables set up through the UI are secured. Obviously, CircleCI itself can access them as well as anybody who can log in to the CircleCI dashboard. Communication is encrypted so nobody else can read those variables.

There is no point for CirleCI stopping a developer from echoing variables in jobs, that's developer's responsibility.

Read [this article](https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/security/#encryption) for more information.